Set layer name in layout legend to hidden
QGIS layout - legend item properties
I am attempting to use pygis to create and format a layout in a number of qgis project files.
The problem I am stuck on is finding the right code to access the settings that will hide the layer name in the layout legend.
The screenshot shows how to do that manually.  Bottom-right, I simply right-click on the layer name and set it to hidden.
I have tried many different approaches without success.  The code bloc below is just the most recent.  The code runs okay.  And debugging for different solutions reported that the setItemVisibilityChecked was set to false.
I don't know whether I am 'accessing' the correct 'object' or not. Or, whether the change is not being committed for some reason?
        # Disable auto-update and manually set the legend layers
        legend_item.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
        legend_model = legend_item.model()
        root = legend_model.rootGroup()
        root.removeAllChildren()
        layer = nation_crop_layers[0]
        root.addLayer(layer)
        
        # Hide the legend items by setting their visibility to unchecked
        for node in root.children():
            if isinstance(node, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
                node.setItemVisibilityChecked(False)

The target outcome is that the text "vw_us_sp_wheat_winter_northern_pl" should not appear in the legend. As in, this image: target outcome
